# Could i run a stormcast eternals body with a head from a space wolf?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I was wondering if I could use a stormcast eternals body but use a space wolves head and run him as a terminator? I got some stormcasts from a small local tournament and I run space wolf army so I was wondering if I could use the stromcasts body in place of a terminators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely you can. The Hobby has a long history of *converting* models, e.g. head swaps, weapon swaps, extra legs/arms/tentacles etc.

If the conversion is likely to cause confusion, just point out what it 'counts as' to your opponent before the game.

Comment: Might be helpful to mention that in any competitive/tournament/organized play, rules may vary, and may require alerting the organizers in addition to the opponent ahead of time of any models that are significantly different from the "normal" model.

Comment: @Tal True - some tournaments aim for wysiwyg ("what you see is what you get") - so best ask around in your area to see what's considered acceptable.

Comment: Be careful though, as Terminator armour is a very distinct look. I've seen a few conversions where the Stormcast models have been used to represent Artificer armour and there's been no issues.